# Override template swagger UI Header name and icon, drf-yasg

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, drf-yasg

I'm trying to customize the swagger ui. I already override the template by adding drf-yasg/swagger-ui.html on templates.

[image: this part]

When I tried to add a header tag It just add above it.
[image: added header]

here's the code from swagger-ui.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>{% block title %} {{ title }}{% endblock %}</title>

    {% block extra_head %}
        {# -- Add any extra HTML heads tags here - except scripts and styles -- #}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block favicon %}
        {# -- Maybe replace the favicon -- #}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'drf-yasg/swagger-ui-dist/favicon-32x32.png' %}"/>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block main_styles %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'drf-yasg/style.css' %}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'drf-yasg/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.css' %}">
    {% endblock %}
    {% block extra_styles %}
        {# -- Add any additional CSS scripts here -- #}
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body class="swagger-body">

{% block extra_body %}
    {# -- Add any header/body markup here (rendered BEFORE the swagger-ui/redoc element) -- #}
    <header>
        <h1>A heading here</h1>
        <p>Posted by John Doe</p>
        <p>Some additional information here</p>
    </header>
{% endblock %}

<div id="swagger-ui"></div>

{% block footer %}
    {# -- Add any footer markup here (rendered AFTER the swagger-ui/redoc element) -- #}
{% endblock %}

<script id="swagger-settings" type="application/json">{{ swagger_settings | safe }}</script>
<script id="oauth2-config" type="application/json">{{ oauth2_config | safe }}</script>

{% block main_scripts %}
    <script src="{% static 'drf-yasg/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-bundle.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'drf-yasg/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'drf-yasg/insQ.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'drf-yasg/immutable.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'drf-yasg/swagger-ui-init.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block extra_scripts %}
    {# -- Add any additional scripts here -- #}
{% endblock %}

<a id="oauth2-redirect-url" href="{% static 'drf-yasg/swagger-ui-dist/oauth2-redirect.html' %}" class="hidden"></a>

{% if USE_SESSION_AUTH %}
    <div id="django-session-auth" class="hidden">
        {% block session_auth_button %}
            {% csrf_token %}

            {% block user_context_message %}
                {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                    <div class="hello">
                        <span class="django-session">Django</span> <span
                            class="label label-primary">{{ request.user }}</span>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endblock %}

            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <div class='btn authorize'>
                    <a id="auth" class="header__btn" href="{{ LOGOUT_URL }}?next={{ request.path }}" data-sw-translate>
                        {% block django_logout_message %}
                            Django Logout
                        {% endblock %}
                    </a>
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <div class='btn authorize'>
                    <a id="auth" class="header__btn" href="{{ LOGIN_URL }}?next={{ request.path }}" data-sw-translate>
                        {% block django_login_message %}
                            Django Login
                        {% endblock %}
                    </a>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
</body>

</html>
```

I tried adding a header that at extra body block, But it just add above the swagger header,

Comment: {% block favicon %}
        {# -- Maybe replace the favicon -- #}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'drf-yasg/swagger-ui-dist/favicon-32x32.png' %}"/>
    {% endblock %}

this block is for icon

Comment: Yes I tried to change it, but it only changes the icon on tabs

Comment: i think so you have to remove that black header completely and put it new custom.

Comment: Yes, how can I do that?

Comment: let me test on my project then i tell you how you will do it OK.  give me 20 mins

Answer (score 0):

i just sufered with the same issue, i could solved it changing a variable of the swaggerUiConfig in the js section of the template. Inside the block "extra scripts" you need to overrite the attribute layout like this:

```
<script>
  swaggerUiConfig.layout = "BaseLayout";
</script>
```

This will take of the black top bar fromt the UI.